# Running pcl/tools/mesh2pcd.cpp in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, build, cmake, point-cloud-library

I have installed pcl-trunk using this link: 
https://github.com/hsean/Capstone-44-Object-Segmentation/wiki/PCL-1.8:-Ubuntu-14.04-Installation-Guide

I need to run mesh2pcd.cpp program contained in the pcl/tools directory, however I don't know how to build it. I thought that it should be available after running the sudo make install command, but it's not working. Is it possible that the program is not running because I now have two different versions of PCL installed in my pc. I had pcl 1.7.2 installed earlier and today I have installed the trunk version.

Why wasn't it installed, why do I have to build it as a standalone program?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: `cmake .. -DBUILD_tools=ON`

PCL's CMake setup is as follows

```
/path/to/pcl
    CMakeLists.txt     (A)
    tools/
        CMakeLists.txt (B)
```

For the most part, every subdirectory underneath `pcl` has a corresponding `BUILD_x` option that will trigger (A) to "call" `pcl/x/CMakeLists.txt`.  The (B) file is not a stand-alone file, and cannot be run on its own.  So the full sequence of events

```
$ cd /path/to/pcl
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ cmake .. -DBUILD_tools=ON
```

Since PCL is a large library with many components, you may want to know what all of those options are.  You can do this either using `cmake-gui`, or if you prefer working in your terminal (woot!), after running `cmake ..` from the `build/` directory you can run `ccmake .` to see all of the options.

For (a lot) more information, please see the [discussion on the PCL mailing list archive](http://www.pcl-users.org/PCL-Tools-td4046077.html).

Comment: Hello,
I am totally new to PCL.I followed the link given by you.

https://github.com/hsean/Capstone-44-Object-Segmentation/wiki/PCL-1.8:-Ubuntu-14.04-Installation-Guide
Successfully done but after "sudo install make" command what is my next steps?

My target is to convert mesh to point cloud.
How do I use the mesh2pcd file which is inside the "pcl/release/bin" folder.
What I want to do is I want to give input a mesh (0r stl file) and want the output as a cloud point form.

What should be my next steps?